# Select elements from 2 different tables to put in a php loop

Tags: php, html, mysql, css, sql

I'm making a web site for a business and in the "car list" I would like to take information from 2 tables of my data base, one for the car info (name, price...) and the other one for the images URL table.

Example of my code:

```
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost","root","","database") or die("1");
$sql = "SELECT * FROM cars WHERE type= '".$cartype."'";
$result = $mysqli->query($sql);

    if($result)
    {
         while($row = $result->fetch_assoc())
         {

                             ?>

                     <table>
                       <tr>
                          <td> HERE IMAGE URL FROM TABLE 2 </td>
                          <td> <?php echo $row['name']; ?> INFO FROM TABLE 1 </td>
                      </td>
                     </table>

                          <?php





                 }

            }
```

How can I connect to table 2 and put the info in my `while` loop?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are going to have to join your two database tables in your select query. To do that you need an id in your photos table that links it to your cars table.

Example:

```
$sql = "SELECT name,url FROM cars,photos WHERE cars.id = photos.car_id AND type= '".$cartype."'";
```

Then use

```
$row['name']; $row['url'];
```

Comment: Thanks I didn't that It was possible!